# How to import a Directory/full package in Intellij for Testing purposes

Tags: unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, kotlin, corda

I'm working on a project that have two separated directory (like two separate applications that we called cordApp), in the first cordapp we have "a, b, c" classes and in the second one we have "d, e, f" classes.
The idea behind is that the second cordapp must be much lighter than the first one because it has to travel on the network, so the size "heaviness" of the first is greater than the second.

We put the testing folder in the first one (the heavier) but I need to test also stuffs from the "lighter" one, how can I import the second one in the first one?
For now my go-for solution is to create the testing folder also in the second one but it's not that good because it will make it heavier.

Any idea on how to import a full directory/full app in the other one?

This is a photo of the project, "cordapp-contract-states" is the light one and has to be imported in "cordapp" 
 [image]

Comment: That "folder" is a [module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/modules.html). You can add the second module as a dependency of the first one using gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the build.gradle file of the CorDapp including the tests to depend on the other CorDapp.

See the example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V2/cordapp/build.gradle#L58